# Smarty: cannot recognize continue tag

Tags: smarty, continue

all im trying to do is to use the simple continue tag but it keeps giving me error like this:

> string(145) "Smarty error: [in module_db_tpl:onlyimage4;image_detail line 26]: syntax error: unrecognized tag 'continue' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 590)"

my code is as follow:

```
{foreach from=$itemlist item="item"}

    < .. SOME CODE ..>

{if $maxCol == $colm}
  </div>
  {assign var ='colm' value = 0}
  {$row++}
  {continue}  **<- THIS IS THE PROBLEM**
{/if}

    <.. SOME CODE ..>
{/foreach}
```

does anyone have any idea whats wrong, I've been googling and see no comments of such sort everyone seem to suggest that this should work..  any ideas guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For smarty 2:
I don't think the tag exists. if you read [this thread](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=64102) you can see that there are people that want it, and a suggestion to fix it like so. (have not tried)

compiler.continue­.php

```
<?php 
function smarty_compiler_con­tinue($contents, &$smarty) 
{ 
return 'continue;'; 
} 
?>
```

(Bold part my addition)

Create these two files **(in this case just one)** and put them into your plugins directory 
(notice the naming convention compiler.xxx.php).

The good news is, for smarty 3 there is such a tag! see [the manual](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.construct.continue), with example:

```
{$data = [1,2,3,4,5]}
  {foreach $data as $value}
    {if $value == 3}
      {* skip this iteration *}
      {continue}
    {/if}
    {$value}
  {/foreach}
  {*
    prints: 1 2 4 5
  *}
```

Comment: its true the tag doesn't exist. and that was really helpful thnks.

Comment: Look at the answer below, it is the correct answer. You just have to wrap it up like this: {$continue}

Comment: Look at the date of the question and of the answer. Now look back at me. I mean: I'll add what this is for, because the `{$continue}` tag is only voor smarty 3.

Comment: by the way, it should obviously NOT be `{$`, not really sure where that came from.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but you need to use: `{$continue}` (including the `$`)

Comment: Surely that would just echo a variable named "continue"? A functional tag with a $ sign would be really odd, and the Smarty 3 manual confirms that there is no such $: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.construct.continue

Comment: @IMSoP I can only tell you that I tracked it down in the docs somewhere, and it did indeed work for me.  I'd come across this question while trying to figure it out myself, and came back here to post an answer once I did.